# How to set autofocus on a popup lead box input field?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Thrive Architect to create a lead box. I want to automatically focus on the input field when the popup appears.

I've tried using `window.onload` to focus on the input, but it doesn't work for the popup. I understand this might be because the popup loads after the initial page load.

How can I achieve autofocus specifically for the input field within the Thrive Architect popup, considering its event handling and rendering processes?

Current code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("inpt").focus();
  };
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content inside popups is loaded dynamically after the initial page load. In such cases, you should use an event that fires after the popup has been fully loaded and is visible.

Here's the code you should try

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('tve.lightbox.show', function() {
    // This event fires after a Thrive Architect lightbox is shown
    document.getElementById("inpt").focus();
  });
</script>
```

Do let me know how it works. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, the script with tve.lightbox.show didn't quite work. I think the event name might be different for Thrive lightboxes. Do you have any suggestions on how to find the correct event name, both for lightboxes and Thrive Leads in general? Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Just for reference, here's the test URL I'm using: https://yoursecretskills.com/test1-2/

Comment: Can you replace "tve.lightbox.show" with "DOMContentLoaded" and try again it if works?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working...

Comment: Can you share the whole or create a project and share the link??

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to create a project, but I can definitely share the link to the test page where I'm trying to implement the script. Do you think that would be helpful?https://yoursecretskills.com/test1-2/